# how to set a style to have rounded corners to the floating action buttons

Tags: android, floating-action-button

i am creating floating buttons using 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'

what i am trying to do is, to add a cutomized rounded corner rectangle to the floating buttons, but there is not way to set my customized rectangle shape to the buttons

please have alook at the floating buttons layout and the curtomized rectangle, and let me know hoe to set a the rounded rectangle corners as a style to the floating action buttons

**round corner**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#CC888888" >
</stroke>

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

**versicherungslisteactivity_vers_view**

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"

    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="100"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"

    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#f5faff"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#3399FF"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#807779"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_bedarfscheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_round_corners"
        fab:fab_label="Bedarfscheck starten"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_angebot_anfordern"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_round_corners"
        fab:fab_label="Neues Angebot anfordern"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_vertragHinzufuegen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_incoming"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        fab:fab_label="Bestehenden Vertrag Hinzufügen"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it, it is the attribute

```
'fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="13dp"'
```

to make rounded corners you have to change the value of this attribute